# Is it possible to sort an object on the basis of array of its keys?

Tags: javascript, object

if have such a condition

```
var list = {
  "you": 100, 
  "me": 75, 
  "foo": 116, 
  "bar": 15
};
```

can i sort this object on the basis of array of keys in like:-

```
[
"me",
"bar",
"you",
"foo"
]
```

Answer should look like:

```
list = {
  "me": 75, 
  "bar": 15,
  "you": 100, 
  "foo": 116
};
```

Comment: Objects do not have a set order. It's not possible to sort them.

Comment: On what basis are you trying to sort it?

Comment: You can have this behavior doing `let result = {}; [ 'me', 'bar', 'you', 'foo' ].forEach(key => result[key] = list[key])` (creating another object in a specific order), but it does not make sense, as @CalvinGodfrey pointed out, an object does not have any set order.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
const orderedList = Object.keys(list).sort((a, b) => list[a] - list[b]);
```

but you will have an `array`, because an `object` cannot have an order and is not possibile to sort its attributes.

Comment: op has already a sorted array of keys.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable answer, but I'd suggest reformatting it to first discuss how object properties don't have order and then suggest the array method, if an array is suitable.

Comment: If i can sort an object on the basis of its keys, then don't you think i can also sort the object on the basis of the array of its key?
Do you my question is incorrect?
@NinaScholz

Comment: @VishalGupta, it's your question, but i mean if you already have an array of sorted keys, you do not need to sort this array. so it's more a questn, why you want a sorted object (which is possible under some preconditions).